# how to identify the original word in a PDF which has been marked for Redact?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, redaction

Assume in a PDF document I redact two different words, This" and "That". using JavaScript in Adobe PDF, I would like to search & find and treat these two Annot objects. But looking at  https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/acro7js.pdf, it appears that these annot objects are alike, i.e. when I list the properties of these two objects, none of them refers to the actual content of these two words. Is there a way to identify the actual original words that these two Annot objects are defined upon?

Comment: Quite unfortunately, there is no immediate link between Adobe's annotations and the text it refers to. The only way to find "the" text is by exhaustively parsing the entire PDF, recording all operations and applying all font manipulations and metrics, and *then* see what is at the position of those annotations.

Comment: I don't have the exact code but here's a method... Acrobat JavaScript will let you iterate over each word in the PDF page by page by using Doc.getPageNumWords(), and Doc. getPageNthWord(). You can then get the word quads using  Doc. getPageNthWordQuads(). You can also iterate over the Annotation objects on the page. Once you have all of the Redact annotation rectangles and all of the word quads, you can look for matches (or near matches).